# Cucumber JS custom formatter

Tags: cucumberjs

I am trying to learn how to write a simple custom formatter for Cucumber JS.

I have read https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/custom_formatters.md

I tried this sample below. But it is not outputting anything. The documentation talks about setting up the underlying **stream** for the log function. But I don't see any **stream** option to set nor do the custom formatter samples have them.

So my question is how do I get this simple sample below to log the output to stdout ?

I am running the tests the following way as mentioned in docs to use this new formatter

./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -f .\simple_formatter.js  ./Features -r ./Steps

```js
const { Formatter, formatterHelpers, Status } = require("cucumber");
const { stdout } = require("process");

class SimpleFormatter extends Formatter {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

    options.eventBroadcaster.on("envelope", (envelope) => {
      if (envelope.testCaseFinished) {
        this.logTestCaseFinished(envelope.testCaseFinished);
      } else if (envelope.testRunFinished) {
        this.logTestRunFinished(envelope.testRunFinished);
      }
    });
  }

  logTestCaseFinished(testCaseFinished) {
    const testCaseAttempt = this.eventDataCollector.getTestCaseAttempt(
      testCaseFinished.testCaseStartedId
    );
    this.log(
      testCaseAttempt.gherkinDocument.feature.name +
        " / " +
        testCaseAttempt.pickle.name +
        "\n"
    );
    const parsed = formatterHelpers.parseTestCaseAttempt({
      cwd: this.cwd,
      snippetBuilder: this.snippetBuilder,
      supportCodeLibrary: this.supportCodeLibrary,
      testCaseAttempt,
    });
    parsed.testSteps.forEach((testStep) => {
      this.log(
        "  " +
          testStep.keyword +
          (testStep.text || "") +
          " - " +
          Status[testStep.result.status] +
          "\n"
      );
    });
    this.log("\n");
  }
  logTestRunFinished(testRunFinished) {
    this.log(testRunFinished.success ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE");
  }
}
module.exports = SimpleFormatter;
```

Comment: Trying to do the same, docs are so incomplete. Looking at other formatters but they are not very simple with multiple levels of inheritance so I'm going to insert `pry` points to thy to figure out what's going on.

I always have this feeling that cucumber is over-engineered and too many major changes are done when previous perfect design failed somewhere.